# How to connect mongodb collection in react js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

How to connect mongodb collection in react js? Is it possible to connect in reactjs else do we need to use node js as a backend?

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far?
Also have a look at https://bezkoder.com/react-node-express-mongodb-mern-stack/

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely you can't connect to mongodb in reactjs.
Why?
To be connected mongodb, it should have mongodb driver on client's side.
But for some reasons like security or so, it doesn't provide such drivers on client's side.
On the contrary, Nodejs(server side language) supports such drivers like mongoose or so...
Since the reason you can't connect to the mongodb on client's side.
Not sure but I guess you heard about firebase. by using firebase you can connect to google datastore because they support such driver on client's side.